# Label Disappearing From ViewController when displaying to External Screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, screen, external

When I connect and display an external screen, my label completely disappears off of my UIViewController App Screen.

Some of my labels are calculations/increments so I can't just simply put another label over the top.

I want to display my labels on my app and external screen at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

```
// TARGET SCORE

var targetScoreInt = 0
@IBOutlet weak var targetScoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var displayTargetScoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var targetScoreRectangle: UILabel!


@IBAction func TargetScoreStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    let targetScoreValue = Int(sender.value)
    displayTargetScoreLabel.text = String(targetScoreValue)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

targetScoreInt = 0
    displayTargetScoreLabel.text =
        String(targetScoreInt)
}


 // TARGET SCORE - EXTERNAL

  targetScoreLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 110.0)
  targetScoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
  targetScoreLabel.frame = CGRect(x:1340, y:715, width: 300, height: 200)
  displayTargetScoreLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 130.0)
  displayTargetScoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
  displayTargetScoreLabel.frame = CGRect(x:1580, y:715, width: 290, height: 200)
  secondScreenView.addSubview(displayTargetScoreLabel)
  secondScreenView.addSubview(targetScoreLabel)
```

Comment: what do you mean by external screen ?

Comment: My app projects various things onto an external display. Like a TV over Apple TV

Comment: Sure it will move off screen if you set frames like that ...  
Not only because of that you should use autolayout to build a flexible layout that is supposed to work on multiple parent views with different sizes.

Comment: So I should use auto layout to correct it?

Comment: I still haven't been able to fix this issue. Any suggestions?